# NHibernate cannot create instance of abstract class

Tags: nhibernate

I have a class hierarchy:

```
Public MustInherit Class SystemSetting
    Public Property System As Integer
    Public Property Sequence As Integer
    Public Property Description As String
    Public Property Notes As String
End Class

Public MustInherit Class SystemSetting(Of T)
    Inherits SystemSetting

    Public MustOverride Property Value As T
End Class

Public NotInheritable Class StringBasedSystemSetting
    Inherits SystemSetting(Of String)

    Public Overrides Property Value As String
End Class
```

I have a mapping:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" 
           assembly="SystemSettings"
           namespace="SystemSettings"
           default-lazy="false">

    <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2"
           name="SystemSetting"
           abstract="true">

         <composite-id>
             <key-property name="System" column="SystemId"/>
             <key-property name="Sequence" column="SettingSeq"/>
         </composite-id>

         <discriminator column="SettingType" not-null="true" force="false"/>

         <property name="Description" column="SettingDescription"/>
         <property name="Notes" column="SettingNotes"/>

         <subclass name="StringBasedSystemSetting" discriminator-value="T">
             <property name="Value" column="SettingText"/>
         </subclass>
     </class>
 </hibernate-mapping>
```

This mapping creates the correct schema and allows me to successfully save and flush an object. However, when I query, via LINQ or QueryOver, I get the exception:

```
Cannot instantiate abstract class or interface
```

I can resolve this by removing the abstract nature of the SystemSetting class. However, I don't want to compromise my class design if possible. Why is NH trying to create instances of SystemSetting when my mapping is clear on its abstract nature and uses a type discriminator?

**Update:**
If I replace the composite Id with an assigned Id it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this. When a composite Id is used, NH has to use instances of the mapped class to represent the Id. This is why it was trying to instantiate a SystemSetting regardless of the 'abstract' mapping attribute.

Changing the design so that the composite Id is represented as its own type fixes the problem. My base class is still abstract and my queries now work.

Comment: Could you explain more details about this?

Comment: Probably best straight from the horse's mouth: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-declaration-compositeid and http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#components-compositeid.